# Function Expected in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've been trying to get the following Javascript to work without any joy.

I keep getting function expected on the call to the confirm dialog.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The gist of the code is that I check firstly to make sure the form validators are not going to fire then I get the values of the two ASPNET radio button lists, then I check if items have been selected in two checkbox lists.

If I have at least one item selected in the checkboxes and either of the radiobutton lists are set to yes then I want to pop the confirm dialog.

```
    function FormSubmissionConfirm() {

    if (Page_ClientValidate()) {

        //get all the relevant form values

        var showConfirm = false;

        var storage = document.getElementsByName("<%: StorageRBL.UniqueID%>");
        var storageAnswer;
        for (var j = 0; j < storage.length; j++) {
            if (storage[j].checked) {
                storageAnswer = storage[j].value;
            }
        }

        var flat = document.getElementsByName("<%: FlatRBL.UniqueID%>");
        var flatAnswer;
        for (var j = 0; j < flat.length; j++) {
            if (flat[j].checked) {
                flatAnswer = flat[j].value;
            }
        }


        var confirm = document.getElementById("<%: preferedlist.ClientID%>");
        var confirmChkBoxCount = confirm.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var confirmAnswer;
        for (var i = 0; i < confirmChkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            if (confirmChkBoxCount[i].checked)
                confirmAnswer = true;
        }

        var reminder = document.getElementById("<%: reminderList.ClientID%>");
        var chkBoxCount = reminder.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var reminderAnswer;
        for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            if (chkBoxCount[i].checked)
                reminderAnswer = true;
        }

        if (reminderAnswer ==true && confirmAnswer == true) {
            if (storageAnswer == "yes" || flatAnswer == "yes") {

                showConfirm = true;

            }
        }

        if (showConfirm)
            return confirm("Please confirm that the details that have been entered are correct");
        else
            return true;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the markup for button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Confirm" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" ID="ConfirmBtn" OnClientClick="if (! FormSubmissionConfirm()) return false;" OnClick="ConfirmBtn_Click" CausesValidation="True" />
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks
Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within this line:

```
var confirm = document.getElementById("<%: preferedlist.ClientID%>");
```

You are creating a confirm variable for the container of the checkboxlist. Then, it is obvious that you cannot use the original confirm box :). Confirm means something else now. Use another variable name.